# Clean Install of Windows 8.1- Will it delete other Partitions?

Tags: windows-7, partitioning

I am going to do a clean install of Windows 8.1 on my pc running Windows 7 64 bit. My question is, if I do a clean install will it delete my Local Disk D and New Volume E? Can I tell it only to install on Drive C so my data on D and E is preserved? Or will everything be deleted.Thanks

Comment: When installing W8 you will have the opportunity to choose which partition to install W8 onto, choose the proper partition and the others will be left intact.

Comment: Why not install Windows 10 Windows 8 is Microsoft mistake like vista where Windows 10 is where they corrected some mistakes

Comment: Yup @SeanClt I plan to update to win 10 once I install 8.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you tell it to wipe or repartition your other partitions, they will be left intact. However, now is the time to make sure you have a backup of this data. If you mess up the installation, you may accidentally ask Windows to erase the data and then you'll be thankful for the backups.